# Does bubble in the buble chamber represented the actural measurement of the particle or the trajectory of the potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, statistical-mechanics, bubbles

The bauble chamber was used as a measurement in the particle physics. Traditionally, the thoughts were that when the particle made an excitation in the chamber, as to physically measured, a bubble was formed, and a sequence of those bubble traced out the particle trajectory.

However, it should be noted that, though the formation of the bubble was perhaps chaotic, the expansion of the bubble was not, and rather followed the classical mechanics, which could be traced back to the exact points of which the mean position and momentum at relative high(classical) precision. Thus, could it be possible that the particle in the bubble chamber never "actually appeared", but rather presented a potential along the trajectory, and the statistical mechanics of the fluid worked out the formation of the bubble itself?

If the bubble was in fact the measure of the particle occurrence, then the traced back occurrences of the bubbles should follow the probability distribution similar to that of the quantum tunneling. If the bubble was the result of the particle potential, then the traced back occurrences of the bubbles should follow the probability distribution similar to that of the statistical mechanics governed fluid properties. Does bubble in the buble chamber represented the actural measurement of the particle or the trajectory of the potential?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particles are quantum mechanical entities and interact with other particles and the atoms in the bubble chambers quantum mechanically. When charged they can hit an electron off the atom , the interaction quantum mechanical,and ionize the atom. A sequence of an ionization trail is the track of the particle, invisible until a rapid expansion of the chamber makes it visible.

> [However, a bubble chamber is sensitive](https://home.cern/news/news/experiments/seeing-invisible-event-displays-particle-physics) to particles passing through only when its contents are superheated after rapid expansion. Bubbles form at this point and the chamber must be recompressed to stop the bubble growth for a picture. This limits the rate at which events can be collected.

The tracks  can be fitted with classical electromagnetic equations of a charged particle in a magnetic field in a fluid.

> Does bubble in the buble chamber represented the actual measurement of the particle or the trajectory of the potential

At the quantum mechanical level the potential between particles is used to solve the equation for scattering and get the wave function which will give the probability of the charged particle interacting and ionizing an atom.